# Travis CI SonarCloud error "Project was never analyzed. A regular analysis is required before a branch analysis"

Tags: maven, sonarqube, code-coverage, travis-ci, sonarcloud

Hi I am automating code coverage on SonarCloud using Travis CI for a `Maven` application.

Now, running the `sonar:sonar` command locally submits the report on SoundCloud and I can see it as shown below with Branch `master`

[image]

Now I have also configured `.travis.yml` file to auto push the report to *SoundCloud* on each build as below

[image]

But when build is triggered by Travis CI it fails with following error

```
[INFO] Load project branches
[INFO] Load project branches (done) | time=114ms
[INFO] Load project pull requests
[INFO] Load project pull requests (done) | time=116ms
[INFO] Load branch configuration
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 27.884 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-05-19T16:47:23Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 93M/496M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar (default-cli) on project safenest-java-server: 

 Project was never analyzed. A regular analysis is required before a branch analysis`
```

I am new to *SonarCloud* and couldn't find much documentation to get help with this. Can somebody explain what exactly `A regular analysis is required` mean? And how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this still an issue today?

Answer (score 3):

You should check following parameters:

1. `Project key` generated during maven build and generated on SonarCloud (or make sure that you set **sonar.projectKey** property that was generated on SonarCloud).
2. Check if provided Token value matching the one on SonarCloud (you can provide your own value on project setup page.

Answer (score 1):

The error message means:

> Please analyze main branch, before you will analyze other branches

You have to build main repository branch (usually `master`) with this configuration on Travis. After that you should be able to analyze all other branches. I hit the same problem when I was trying to analyze a feature branch which integrates my project with [SonarCloud](https://sonarcloud.io/) for the first time. I just merged my feature to `master`, pushed, and my project has been analyzed successfully. My configuration is similar to yours:

```
language: java
jdk: openjdk8
env: MVN_VERSION='3.6.0'
addons:
  sonarcloud:
    organization: $SONAR_ORGANIZATION
    token:
      secure: $SONAR_TOKEN
before_install:
  - wget https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/$MVN_VERSION/apache-maven-$MVN_VERSION-bin.zip
  - unzip -qq apache-maven-$MVN_VERSION-bin.zip
  - export M2_HOME=$PWD/apache-maven-$MVN_VERSION
  - export PATH=$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH
script:
  - mvn -B -e verify site
  - if [ -n "$SONAR_TOKEN" ]; then
      mvn -B -e sonar:sonar -Dsonar.sources=pom.xml,src/main;
    fi
```